# Populating new Dataframe in Python taking too long, need to remove explicit recursive loops to improve performance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, recursion

I am building a Python code to analyze the growth of COVID-19 across different nations, I am using the OWID database to get the latest values each time the code is run:

```
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv")
data.to_csv('covid.csv')
data
```

OWID not just provides the CSV file but also XLSX and JSON formats, JSON has a 3D structure even, might that help with the efficiency?

I am trying to create a new Dataframe with the country name as the column headings and date range containing all the listed dates as the index:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

buffer = 30

cases = pd.DataFrame(columns=data['location'].drop_duplicates(),
                     index=pd.date_range(start= data['date'].min() - datetime.timedelta(buffer), end=data['date'].max()))
deaths = pd.DataFrame(columns=data['location'].drop_duplicates(),
                      index=pd.date_range(start= data['date'].min() - datetime.timedelta(buffer), end=data['date'].max()))
```

I am doing differentials on the values so I need to make sure each consecutive element is at equal time-steps (1 day).

The database does not have all the dates within the daterage for most countries, many of them even have data missing for dates in the middle of the range. All I could think of was using recursive loops to populate the new dataframe:

```
location = data['location'].drop_duplicates()
date_range = pd.date_range(data['date'].min(), data['date'].max())

for l, t in itertools.product(location, date_range):
    c = data.loc[(data['location'] == l) & (data['date'] == t), 'total_cases']
    d = data.loc[(data['location'] == l) & (data['date'] == t), 'total_deaths']
    if c.size != 0:
        cases[l][t] = c.iloc[0]
    if d.size != 0:
        deaths[l][t] = d.iloc[0]
```

This gets the job done but it takes more than **20 Min** to complete on my fairly good PC. I know there is some way to do this without using explicit loops but I am new to python.

Comment: Seems like you may want to start with reshaping the data, rather than populating a new dataframe with a loop. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html

Comment: It would be better to edit your question and put there sample input data (e.g. ~10 rows, 3-4columns) and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the faster implementation.
The key functions are [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot) and [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).
You can use [interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) function for smarter filling of NaN values.

```py
import pandas as pd

filename = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(
    filename, 
    # parse dates while reading
    parse_dates=["date"],
    # select subset of columns
    usecols=["date", "location", "total_cases", "total_deaths"], 
)

locations = df["location"].unique()
date_range = pd.date_range(df["date"].min(), df["date"].max())

# select needed columns and reshape
cases = (
    # turn location into columns and date into index
    pd.pivot(df, index="date", columns="location", values="total_cases")
    # fill missing dates
    .reindex(date_range)
    # fill missing locations
    .reindex(columns=locations)
    # fill NaN in total_cases using the previous value
    # another good option is .interpolate("time")
    .fillna(method="ffill")
    # sort columns
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)

# use the same logic for `total_deaths`
...
```

Comment: That works like a charm! Thank you for the extra addition of parse_dates and the interpolate("time") methods, coming from C/C++ these look like magic to me.

Comment: The first rule of pandas: 'avoid loops')

Comment: Amen. I need to get more familiar with python, it's truly a powerful tool for data analytics.